# How to reach a joined field with Symfony 2?

Tags: php, symfony, doctrine-orm

I have a joined query:

```
$query = $this
    ->getEm()
    ->getRepository("MovementHeader")
    ->createQueryBuilder('d')
    ->leftJoin('MovementDetail', 'stockmovementdetail', 'WITH', 'stockmovementdetail.movementId = d.id')
```

now how to reach "movementdetail" ?

Comment: Haven't you already reached it? Can you show us what the object MovementHeader and MovementDetail contains? What are their attributes? Also where do you want to reach it? In the query? In php ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Since your question is very vague I'm going to answer generally. If you want more specific information, please provide more specific information.

Assuming movement header has a field that is linked to the MovementDetail entity (let's call it movementDetail). You could do the following :

```
$query = $this
    ->getEm()
    ->getRepository("MovementHeader")
    ->createQueryBuilder('mh')
    ->select('mh','md')
    ->innerJoin('mh.movementDetail','md')
    ->where(/* Now in the where cause, 
               you can select what ever 
               you want from mh or md*/)
    ->setParameters(array(/* ... */))
```

Here are some examples of where you can use :

```
->where('mh.id = :id') //Could used when you want to retrieve a specific header
->where('md.field IN (:list)') // Where you want to retrive all the mh 
                               // (and their md) that contains the fields
```

You can also do multiple conditions like this

```
->where('mh.field = :value AND md.otherField = :value2')
```

And then, you have to set the parameters accordingly.

Once you get the results you can access the fields with the normal getters and setters.